# Pre populate Sql data based on Enums or Constants

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fill db pre populated data from sql script where I have two type of constants or enums.

**Platform: DG, NK**

**Department : KK, TG, LO, NP, UI, BG, ED, CC.**

Task: To generate a sequential number using procedural loop and for each combination using above value we need to generate key and put in data base with count or sequence value.

Database columns are based on JPA abstract entity:

```
id, created_by, created_at, status, updated_by, updated_at, uuid, count, category_key
```

Now single row would be one combination which is formed using this pattern,
**Department_Platform_SequenceNumber :: example => KK_DG_1,....KK_DG_10000, KK_NK_1,....KK_NK_10000**

This is for 10k entries for 10k sequence of each combinations. It follows for other as well.

**Approach:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE KeyGeneration;

    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE LoopDemo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    DECLARE dep  VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE plat  VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE str VARCHAR(30);

    SET x = 1;
    SET dep =  'KK'; # help to initialize enums or constants
    SET plat =  'DG'; # help to initialize enums or constants
    count_val: LOOP
        IF x=10000 THEN 
            LEAVE  count_val;
        END  IF;
        SET  str = CONCAT(dep,'_',plat,'_',x); 
        insert into counter_key values(id, created_by, created_at, status, updated_by, updated_at, uuid, x, str);
        SET  x = x + 1;
    END LOOP;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

call LoopDemo();
```

but this is wrong since what I want is that atleast id to be updated if possible created_at and other fields as well also the loop will return last value I guess I want to get each value.

**TABLE COLUMNS UPDATED**
**UPDATED:** id, count, counter_key, status

@Akina answer applied as per my new table but syntax error

```
WITH RECURSIVE
number AS ( SELECT 1 number 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT number + 1 FROM cte WHERE number < 10000 ),
platform AS ( SELECT 'DG' platform
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'NK' ),
department AS ( SELECT 'KK' department
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'TG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'LO'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'NP'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'UI'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'BG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'ED'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'CC' )               
INSERT INTO counter_key 
SELECT null, number, CONCAT_WS('_', department, platform, number), 1
FROM department
CROSS JOIN platform
CROSS JOIN number;
```

Comment: In general, you can just use an auto-incremented column to define a unique key for the table.  There is no need for a "smart" code.

Comment: ...indeed, this kind of thing is almost certainly counterproductive

Comment: @GordonLinoff To be more meaningful and somewhat working code I updated this but now I am getting duplicate entry since I am not setting uuid and it takes blank each time since I cant remove as this is a jpa abstract entity comes with some necessary columns like status, created_by,updated_at etc. Please see code if you can remove the error and help me

Comment: @Strawberry Also in above code if you see I need to manually execute each combination of 10000 entries why cant I do this in mysql `enumSetVar.forEach(key->setTabledataFromProcedure(key));`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
number AS ( SELECT 1 number 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT number + 1 FROM cte WHERE number < 10000 ),
platform AS ( SELECT 'DG' platform
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'NK' ),
department AS ( SELECT 'KK' department
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'TG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'LO'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'NP'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'UI'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'BG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'ED'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'CC' )
INSERT INTO counter_key 
SELECT @id, @created_by, @created_at, @status, @updated_by, @updated_at, @uuid, @x, 
       CONCAT_WS('_', department, platform, number)
FROM department
CROSS JOIN platform
CROSS JOIN number;
```

where `@id, @created_by, @created_at, @status, @updated_by, @updated_at, @uuid, @x` must be replaced with literal values taken from somewhere.

Comment: this looks good but where do I put this as a whole since I am getting error "With" is not valid at this position for this server version....if you have full version please paste it

Comment: @Kramer Specify **precise** version of your MySQL server (you'd do this from the same beginning).

Comment: mysql command `select @@version;` got this ::: **8.0.22**

Comment: @Kramer The query MUST work on this version. Check the value of [`@@cte_max_recursion_depth`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_cte_max_recursion_depth) system variable, adjust its value if needed (default value is 1000, but 10000 or higher needed for this query). Also you may have a problem with your client/connection software which does not know about CTE, upgrade it in this case.

Comment: Getting error here after execution `INSERT INTO counter_key  SELECT @id, @status, @x, CONCAT_WS('_', dep' at line 23`

Comment: so I guess I might resolve this by declaring @variable by getting some value so I removed everything,,,except `INSERT INTO counter_key 
SELECT number, CONCAT_WS('_', department, platform, number)` now default value for status is 1 but id is auto generated...now tell me what is wrong

Comment: can you specify the syntax error and yes `@@cte_max_recursion_depth` indeed 1000 but shouldn't be a problem in syntax

Comment: @Kramer *Getting error ... at line 23* Have you read the last sentence of my answer? In your question you have not specified where the values for all another columns must be taken, and I put placeholders for these values.

Comment: yes I know I get it but like I said id should be autogenerated and status is always true,,,,can we achieve this with your above query?

Comment: @Kramer *id should be autogenerated* Set it to NULL instead of @id. *status is always true* set it to TRUE instead of @status. `.. SELECT NULL, @created_by, @created_at, TRUE, @updated_by, @updated_at, @uuid, @x, ..`

Comment: Updated my table columns please see bottom to my question and I did this to avoid confusion but still error in syntax...please see answer updated your answer there

Comment: please see my question now I am not adding any column which could be getting values elsewhere still error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224183/discussion-between-kramer-and-akina).